# String variable value as object key errors on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have experienced a problem on a page under IE11, which crashes a page there. The problematic code essentially takes a String dynamically from the server, initializes a variable with that and later uses it as object key. To make the question digestible, I have written a small script:

```
var bar = "b";
var foo = {[bar]: "Orson oson a borsos borsós fosos koros boros korsón"};
```

This works under Chrome, FireFox and Microsoft Edge alike, but under IE11, I get the following error:

> Expected identifier, string or number

Why is IE11 not allowing this and how should I solve this?

Comment: Maybe the code is `ES6` or `ES7` related. Try `var bar = "b", foo = {}; foo[bar] = "Orson oson a borsos borsós fosos koros boros korsón";`

Comment: @Mr_Green, that works, but I wonder about the cause my code throws the error.

Comment: IE11 supports `ES5` but not new versions like `ES6` or `ES7`. In `ES5` you can't place a variable in key of object. Hence, the error.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but why not just doing ```key = String([bar])``` and then use key?

Comment: @Ness, can you show me the script you are thinking about?

Comment: @Ness, that will have no syntax error, but if you console.log(foo); you will see that it has a member called key which should not be there and there is no member called b, which should be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE11 is old and doesn't support that syntax ... syntactical changes in ES2015+ are not always easy to implement in old tired browsers - though with this you could do

```
var bar = "b";
var foo = {};
foo[bar] = "Orson oson a borsos borsós fosos koros boros korsón";
```

using babel, however, the code translates to (ES2015-loose preset)

```
var _foo;

var bar = "b";
var foo = (_foo = {}, _foo[bar] = "Orson oson a borsos borsós fosos koros boros korsón", _foo);
```

or (ES2015 preset)

```
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { 
    if (key in obj) { 
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { 
            value: value, 
            enumerable: true, 
            configurable: true, 
            writable: true 
        }); 
    } else { 
        obj[key] = value; 
    } 
    return obj; 
}

var bar = "b";
var foo = _defineProperty({}, bar, "Orson oson a borsos borsós fosos koros boros korsón");
```

This syntax is referred to as [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)